# Angular9 upload multiple documents how to send data in API

Tags: angular

I need to upload multiple document files and need to pass data in POST API. This is my post-man API details with post data.

> how to set the same format of an array of docs from the front-end side as the postman.

[image]

This is what I have tried but didn't work

```
  getImageDetailsFormData(files): FormData {
    const formData = new FormData();
    const docDetails = [];
    let counter = 1;

    for (const file of files) {
      formData.append(`doc${counter}`, file, file.name);
      docDetails.push({
        fileName: `doc${counter}`, dateTimeCaptured: new Date(file.lastModified)
      });
      counter++;
    }
    formData.append('checklist', JSON.stringify(docDetails));
    return formData;
  }
```